# (Vue.js) error: 'token' is not defined (no-undef) with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, token

```
axios.post(`${this.url}/auth/login`, {
    email: this.email,
    pw: this.pw
  })
  .then( response => { 
    if (response.status === 200) {
      this.$swal('환영합니다!','로그인에 성공하였습니다.','success')
      this.$store.state.login = true
      console.log(response.data.data.x-access-token)
      this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
    }
  })
  .catch( error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 400) {
      this.$swal('오류','이메일 또는 비밀번호가 올바르지 않습니다.','error')
    }
  })
```

An error occurs when this code is executed.

> error: 'token' is not defined (no-undef)

The value of response at login is

```
data:
  is_student: true
  is_worker: false
  x-access-token: "token"
message: "로그인 성공."
status: 200
```

But I can't access token by using `response.data.data.x-access-token`. 
 How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use: `response.data.data['x-access-token']`

Comment: Oh, so simply! Thank U.